# Array of pointers to RGB structures always pointing to the first pixel

Tags: c, pointers, struct

bmp.h

```
// BMP-related data types based on Microsoft's own

#include <stdint.h>

// aliases for C/C++ primitive data types
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230309.aspx
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

// information about the type, size, and layout of a file
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183374(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPFILEHEADER;

// information about the dimensions and color format
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
BITMAPINFOHEADER;

// relative intensities of red, green, and blue
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162939(v=vs.85).aspx
typedef struct
{
    BYTE rgbtBlue;
    BYTE rgbtGreen;
    BYTE rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

resize.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

// remember factor and filenames
int factor = atoi(argv[1]);
char *infile = argv[2];
char *outfile = argv[3];

// open input file
FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 2;
}

// open output file
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
if (outptr == NULL)
{
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
    return 3;
}

// read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

// read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

// ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
    bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
{
    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
    return 4;
}

// update outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
BITMAPINFOHEADER obi = bi;
obi.biWidth *= factor;
obi.biHeight *= factor;

// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&obi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

// determine padding for scanlines
int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// determine outfile's padding
int out_padding = (4 - (obi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

// remember pixels in an array
RGBTRIPLE * array[obi.biWidth];

// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    array[0] = NULL;
    int idx = 0;

    printf("----------------------\nReading from file.\n----------------------\n");
    // iterate over pixels in scanline
    for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
    {
        // temporary storage
        RGBTRIPLE triple;

        // read RGB triple from infile
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

        // write to array n times
        for(int k = 0; k < factor; k++)
        {
            array[idx] = &triple;
            printf("scanline n°%d, pixel n°%d, array[%d] = %p, blue: %i, green: %i, red: %i\n", i, j, k, array[k], triple.rgbtBlue, triple.rgbtGreen, triple.rgbtRed);
            ++idx;
        }
    }
    printf("\nNow writing to outfile...\n\n");
    // for n times
    for (int x = 0; x < factor; x++)
    {
        // write array to outfile
        for(int y = 0; y < obi.biWidth; y++)
        {
            fwrite(array[y], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            printf("scanline n°%d, array[%d] = %p\n", i, y, array[y]);
        }

        // write padding to outfile
        for(int k = 0; k < out_padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // skip over padding, if any
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
}

// close infile
fclose(inptr);

// close outfile
fclose(outptr);

// success
return 0;
}
```

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XNQO.png)

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4xhL.png)

I'm trying to write a program in C which resizes BMP files. The program takes three arguments (a small BMP file, the name of a large BMP file to be created from the small BMP, and a factor by which to increment the small BMP).

To do so, I store each scanline of pixels to be repeated n times in an array of pointers which I will use to write to the new output file. My problem is that, although the RGB values change when it reaches the white pixels, each pointer has the same address. Consequently, the output file is just a green box instead of a green box with white pixels in the center. I can't figure out why, could someone explain why the address is always the same

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: `RGBTRIPLE * array[obi.biWidth];` Why do you need this? What about `RGBTRIPLE array[obi.biWidth];`? Then fix another parts of the code accordingly: `array[idx] = triple;` etc.

Comment: You don't need an array of pointers here at all. An array of RGB triples is qute enough. Bear in mind that automatic variable-length arrays are dangerous and you most certainly want to use `malloc` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RGBTRIPLE * array[obi.biWidth];
> ```

Change this to `RGBTRIPLE array[obi.biWidth];` or `RGBTRIPLE *array = malloc(...)` as suggested in comments.

Change `array[idx] = &triple;` to `array[idx] = triple;`

> ```
> for(int y = 0; y < obi.biWidth; y++)
> {
>     fwrite(array[y], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
> }
> ```

You can write the whole array instead of writing one element at a time:

```
RGBTRIPLE *array = malloc(obi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
for(int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
    {
        RGBTRIPLE triple;
        fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

        for(int k = 0; k < factor; k++)
            array[j * factor + k] = triple;
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < factor; x++)
    {
        fwrite(array, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), obi.biWidth, outptr);

        for(int k = 0; k < out_padding; k++)
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
    }

    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
}
free(array);
```

You should also change the value for `BITMAPFILEHEADER`'s `bfSize`:

```
int out_padding = (4 - (obi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
bf.bfSize = 54 + (obi.biWidth * 3 + out_padding) * obi.biHeight;//total file size
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);
```